# Accounting for a float in C

Tags: c, floating-point

So I adjusted the code and it seems to work minus one flaw. The shrink is now a float, but not returning the correct answer. when I attempt to shrink 9 for instance it returns 4.0 not 4.5...... 13 returns 6.0? New code is below:

## include

int main ()

{

/* variable definition: */

int intValue, menuSelect,Results;
    float sResults;

intValue = 1;

// While a positive number

while (intValue > 0)

{

```
 printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");

 scanf("%d", &intValue);
```

if (intValue > 0)

{

```
 printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, Enter 3 to Calculate Shrink \n: ");

 scanf("%d", &menuSelect);

 if (menuSelect == 1)

 {

   // Call the Square Function

   Results = Square(intValue);

   printf("Square of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results);

 }

 else if (menuSelect == 2)

 {

   // Call the Cube function

   Results = Cube(intValue);

   printf("Cube of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results);

 }

 else if (menuSelect == 3)

 {

    sResults = Shrink(intValue);

    printf("shrink of %d is %f\n", intValue,sResults);

 }


 else

   printf("Invalid menu item, only 1 or 2 or 3 is accepted\n");

 }
```

}

return 0;

}

/* function returning the Square of a number */

int Square(int value)

{

return value*value;

}

/* function returning the Cube of a number */

int Cube(int value)

{
   return value*value*value;

}

int Shrink(int value)

{

```
return value*1/2;
```

}

Comment: Try putting the prototype for Shrink() before main(), or simply move main() to the bottom of the code. Then please tell us which errors you encounter.

Comment: Be more specific. Post the errors that you are getting.

Comment: `float Shrink(int value){ return value*0.5;}` and `printf("shrink of %d is %f\n", intValue,Results);` with `float Results;`

Comment: `sResult = Shrink(intValue);`...

Comment: `return value * 1/2;` Most likely the constant part of the expression is evaluated at compile time and since it's an integer division `1/2 == 0`. Try `return value / 2;` instead.

Comment: Read also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @dxiv `value` is declared as `int` too.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, `return value / 2;` will perform an integer division and return its result e.g. `10 / 2 == 5` for the given example.

Comment: FWIW, it is absolutely clear what is being asked here: why does Shrink always return 0? Obviously because `1 / 2` is being evaluated as 0, but that looks like a bug to me, since `*` and `/` have the same precendence and left-to-right associativity, so it should be `(value * 1) / 2`, as @xdiv already commented below. Several compilers I tried return Shrink(10) as 5 and that is correct

Comment: So I adjusted the code (above) and it seems to work minus one flaw. The shrink is now a float, but not returning the correct answer. when I attempt to shrink 9 for instance it returns 4.0 not 4.5...... 13 returns 6.0?

Answer (score 2):

```
Results = Shrink(intValue);

printf("shrink of %d is %f\n", intValue,sResults);
```

You're storing the result in `Results`, but then printing `sResults`.  Those are two different variables, and `sResults` is still zero because it hasn't been assigned a value.  Change `sResults` to `Results` in your `printf` statement.

However, since you're doing integer division, you'll get a result that's truncated to an integer:  `Shrink(5)` will return 2.  To fix that, you'll need to change `Shrink` to take a `float` argument instead of `int`, return `float` instead of `int`, and assign its result to `sResult` instead of `Result`.

---

Also, you're probably getting compiler warnings about the `Square`, `Cube`, and `Shrink` functions being undeclared.  Those happen because the code that calls the functions is before the code that says what they are.  It hasn't caused an actual problem for you *yet*, because the compiler handles the situation by assuming that each function takes an `int` argument and returns an `int` result, which coincidentally happens to be true.  But if you change any of the functions to operate on `float` instead of `int`, your program will break because the calls will still be compiled as if they were `int`.

Move the three math functions up above `main`, *or* leave them at the bottom and put these lines before `main`:

```
int Square(int value);
int Cube(int value);
int Shrink(int value);
```

Those are called declarations, and they tell the compiler what types the functions operate on, so it knows how to handle them even before it sees their implementation.  If you change the functions to operate on `float` instead of `int`, change the declarations to match.